# Axon Mongo EventStore, able to publish and store but could not consume events

Tags: mongodb, axon

I am using Mongo as EventStore with SimpleCommandBus.
[AxonConfig File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4nGr.png)
I am able to see domain events in the store. After enabling
[Mongo DB Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bRCV.png)

I am expecting EventHandlers to be called after AggregateLifeCycle.apply() method call.

There are no errors and from the logs, I see that events EventBus.publishEvent and EventBus.commitEvents but I don't see EventHandler consuming these events. Using Axon Server earlier, I tested sample code it worked fine but once I updated to use Mongo as EventStore and SimpleCommandBus, this happened. Am I missing something.

[EventHandler screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cwvjn.png)

Comment: I am able to make this work by adding the below properties. In the monitoring logs, I can see for event processor process along with event handler calls.

```
axon:
  axonserver:
    enabled: false
  eventhandling:
    processors:
      eventProcessorName:
        source: embeddedEventStore #this is configured in AxonConfig.java
        mode: tracking
```

Answer (score 0):

This should not be a problem. [This project](https://github.com/gklijs/gifcard-kafka-mongo) is a variation of the giftcard demo, but without Axon Server.

There are some other problems with using MongoDB as event store through. [This blog](https://www.axoniq.io/blog/axonserver-vs-mongodb-for-eventstore) goes into the details.